# 360 degree panorama shots and YouTube

Tags: 360-panorama

I have some images (not photos or videos, but 3d still renders) that I want to upload as 360 panoramas on youtube. There are six different images, one for each face of a cube. Does youtube support these types of images? What steps need to be taken to get them on there? Are there tools to process the images, or does youtube accept them in this format? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm uninformed, but YouTube is for videos. You need to upload a video. What are you imagining your YouTube video would be? You need software to create a 3D environment using your images, and then render a (non-interactive) video out of that. That doesn't seem like a photography question to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about photography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youtube only accepts 360º *video*, not stills, so you'd have to render it as a video, first, so no, you cannot use a cubic map directly.

Youtube's 360º video format is basically using the 360ºx180º equirectangular mapping for each frame of the video, so you'd also have to convert the cube faces you have to equirectangular with a tool like [Pano2VR](https://ggnome.com/wiki/Converting_Images_%28Pano2VR%29) or [Hugin](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/88258/how-do-i-make-equirectangular-with-hugin-starting-6-pics-cubic-projection). You would then have to [fill a video track with that image for some duration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcbAw8hS35A).

Comment: That is unfortunate. I may test it out anyway to compare the results.